# composition relation of $R^3$

Tags: relations

I need verification if my answer is right in this composition of relations problem.

If *A = {1,2,3}* and Let *R = {(1,2), (1,3), (2,2), (3,3)}* be a relation from set A to set A. What would be the relation of $R^3$?

My answer is {(1,2),(1,3),(2,2),(3,3)}. Thank you!

Comment: That is correct. Transitive relations are unchanged by composition with themselves.

Comment: Okay. Thank you!